# Why isn't my item in an array getting updated?

Tags: .net, vb.net, arrays, .net-2.0

I have an array of objects, I find the item by index, assign a value but then looking at the array the item doesn't show the updated value.

```
Public Structure Cheque
    Public Id As String
    Public Status As Byte
    Public Amount As String
    Public WarrantNo As String
End Structure

Public Class ChequeCollection

    Private chequeColl() As Cheque 'This is populated ok

Public Sub UpdateChequeAmount(ByVal Id As String, ByVal Amount As String)
        SyncLock lockObject
            Dim idx As Integer = Get_idx(Id) 'Finds it ok
            If idx <> -1 Then
                Dim cheque As Cheque = chequeColl(idx)
                cheque.Amount = Amount 'Updates value ok but if you look in chequeColl the value isn't there
            End If
        End SyncLock
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you've made `Cheque` a `Structure` rather than a `Class`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because value types are copied everywhere they're used - you're updating your copy of the value type that's in the cheque variable, as opposed to the copy within the array.

You'd need to update the copy in the array:

```
            Dim cheque As Cheque = chequeColl(idx)
            cheque.Amount = Amount 'Updates value ok but if you look in chequeColl the value isn't there
            chequeColl(idx) = cheque
```

---

And of course, always worth reading ["The Truth About Value Types"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx) by Mr. Lippert

Comment: But surely the cheque is a reference type so it should then get reflected back into the array.

Comment: @Jon - it would be a refernce type if you'd declared it as a `Class` rather than a `Structure`. In that case, all references to a particular cheque (both your cheque variable, and the slot in the array) would be referring to the same instance of cheque, and so of course changes would be visible.

Comment: So a structure is considered a value type?

Comment: @Jon - yes. Read all about Structure on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k69kzbs1(v=vs.80).aspx (see the Remarks section - "The Structure statement defines a composite value type that..."

Comment: You learn something everyday. Thanks. I've now made it a class

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim cheque As Cheque = chequeColl(idx)
cheque.Amount = Amount
```

with:

```
chequeColl(idx).Amount = Amount
```

how does it work then ?

Comment: That works. WTF! Strangely after that if I do the same logic as above and read the value it has it. So there seems to be something weird going on when setting values.

Comment: @Jon: The thing that mutates when you mutate a mutable value type is a *variable*. That's why variables are called "variables", because they vary. In the first code fragment the value is copied to the local variable, so the assignment of "Amount" varies that variable. In the second fragment, chequeColl(idx) is the variable; array slots are variables. So that is the thing that varies.  This is very confusing; that is why mutable value types are a "worst practice" in .NET. If you intend the thing to have individually mutable fields then make it a class.